# Can width:auto expand the div beyond screen width

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically creating chart whose width might keep on increasing. It is placed inside a container with fixed width and auto scroll. So the chart scrolls if it is wider than the container.

My issue is that the width of the chart is not fixed, it depends on the content.
**Can I use width:auto to set the chart width as per its need. If not is there any way with just CSS to achieve it.**

EDITS:I want the blocks to be in a single line even if the container has to have scroll. Is this possible just using CSS.

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  background:#e3e3e3;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.sidebar{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  background:#666;
  height:200px;
}
.chart{
  margin:50px 20px;
}
.block{width:100px;float:left;background:#ccc;margin:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
CONTAINER
  <div class="chart">
    <div class="block">100</div>
    <div class="block">200</div>
    <div class="block">300</div>
    <div class="block">400</div>
    <div class="block">500</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
SIDEBAR
</div>
```

The blocks have to be aligned horizontally. Updating with a image to show the output layout

Comment: He meant the blank code spaces before the fiddle link, as no fiddle link is allowed without some code within the question as well. I removed link and added a snippet.

Comment: Oh. A cheap trick(hack). Hehehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your `.block` from `float: left` to `display: inline-block` and set `white-space: nowrap` on your `.chart`, they will line up horizontal.

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  background:#e3e3e3;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.sidebar{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  background:#666;
  height:200px;
}
.chart{
  margin:50px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.block{width:100px;background:#ccc;margin:10px;display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
CONTAINER
  <div class="chart">
    <div class="block">100</div>
    <div class="block">200</div>
    <div class="block">300</div>
    <div class="block">400</div>
    <div class="block">500</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
SIDEBAR
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks LGSon. This option also solves my problem. Had to apply vertical-align as top, since my elements had different heights. As I said, I thought javascript was the only option to calculate the width to set it horizontal, but I got two solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `display: table-cell;`

only CSS changed :

```
.container{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  background:#e3e3e3;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.sidebar{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  background:#666;
  height:200px;
}
.chart{
  margin:50px 20px;
}
.block{width:100px;background:#ccc;padding:10px;display: table-cell;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/us5Ljz7t/4/

Comment: table-cell does solve the issue. Thank you very much. But the inline-block also gives me the result. I am going to go with that option rather than table-cell for now. Got two solutions to a problem I thought had no CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

`white-space:nowrap` will do the trick.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background: #666;
  height: 200px;
}
.chart {
  /* width:800px;*/
  white-space: nowrap; /* ← added */
  margin: 50px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  CONTAINER
  <div class="chart">
    Dynamically adding chart content here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  SIDEBAR
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I guess I didn't explain the problem throughly. I have updated the question and the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/thomas014/us5Ljz7t/2/

Comment: Yeah, white-space: nowrap doesn't work very well with inner floating blocks. However, if you replace the float for the blocks with display:inline-block, it will work. Oh, I see that's identical to the answer LGSon gave. Oh well, that'll teach me to walk away from my keyboard for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the `width: inherit`, so that the width will be taken from the parent element, that is the container div.

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  width:300px;
  background:#e3e3e3;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.sidebar{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  background:#666;
  height:200px;
}
.chart{
  margin:50px 20px;
  width: inherit
}
.block{width:100px;float:left;background:#ccc;margin:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
CONTAINER
  <div class="chart">
    <div class="block">100</div>
    <div class="block">200</div>
    <div class="block">300</div>
    <div class="block">400</div>
    <div class="block">500</div>
    <div class="block">100</div>
    <div class="block">200</div>
    <div class="block">300</div>
    <div class="block">400</div>
    <div class="block">500</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
SIDEBAR
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thomas014/us5Ljz7t/2/)

Comment: The blocks have to be aligned horizontally in a single line.